# Titanium ListView how do show image depending status of a task with Alloy?

Tags: listview, titanium

I am starting my second week using Titanium, I do not know how can I show an image depending in the status of a task, for example I want to show in a ListView a green icon checked and if the task is not completed a blank checked.

I've tried with a query to the database with this function

```
function mostrarLista(){

    var tasks = Alloy.createCollection('todo');
        // The table name is the same as the collection_name value from the 'config.adapter' object. This may be different from the model name.
        var table = tasks.config.adapter.collection_name;
        // use a simple query
        var query = tasks.fetch({query:'select status from ' + table + ' where status=" + 1 + "'});
        //books.fetch({query: {statement: 'DELETE from ' + table + ' where title = ?', params: [args.titulo] }});


    var section = $.elementsOnList;
        var item = section;
        var currentImage = item.icon.image;

    if(query==1){
    item.icon.image = "images/checked.png" ;
        }else{
    item.icon.image = "images/blank_check.png";
    }



}
```

But I do not exactly how set the image to the **ListView** dinamically without using an event.

This is what I have in the controlller

listdo.js

```
    var args = arguments[0] || {};

var myTasks=Alloy.Collections.todo;
    myTasks.fetch();



//FUNCION PARA CAMBIAR IMAGEN 
function checked(e){
        //$.alertDialog.show();

        //$.alertDialog.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
             // Get the clicked item

        var section = $.elementsOnList.sections[e.sectionIndex];
        var item = section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
        var currentImage = item.icon.image;


                //Antiguo
                     if(currentImage =="images/blank_check.png" && item.properties.estatus ==1){    
                        item.icon.image = "images/checked.png" ;

                        //Change the status in order to know which task has or not completed
                        updateID(item.properties.idTareas, 2);
                        alert('Tarea realizada');
                        //end update status

                     }else{
                        item.icon.image = "images/blank_check.png";
                        updateID(item.properties.idTareas, 1);
                        alert('Tarea activa');
                    }


        section.updateItemAt(e.itemIndex, item);

}

function showDetailTask(event){

    var itemSection = $.elementsOnList.sections[event.sectionIndex]; // Get the section of the clicked item
     // Get the clicked item from that section
    var item = itemSection.getItemAt(event.itemIndex);

    var args= {
        idTareas: item.properties.idTareas,
        nombre: item.properties.nombre, //Lo que captura el array 
        hora: item.properties.hora,
        fecCreacion: item.properties.fecCreacion, //Lo que captura el array 
        fechaTarea: item.properties.fechaTarea,
        descripcion: item.properties.descripcion, //Lo que captura el array 
        estatus: item.properties.estatus

    };
    var taskdetail = Alloy.createController("taskdetail", args).getView();
    taskdetail.open();

}

function updateID(idTareas, status){
    var task = myTasks.get(idTareas);
    task.set({
        "status":status  //Por defecto es 1 cuando esta activo si es cero quiere decir que está inactivo
    }).save();

}
```

and in my ListView

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="todo" /> <!--Capture the collections I want to show -->
        <Tab id="tabPrincipal" title="Listado de tareas">       
    <Window>

                <AlertDialog id="alertDialog" title="Información" message="¿Desea marcar como completada está tarea?" cancel="1">
                        <ButtonNames>
                            <ButtonName>Si</ButtonName>
                            <ButtonName>No</ButtonName>
                        </ButtonNames>          
                              <!--
                            Only on Android, an additional view can be added to be rendered in
                            the AlertDialog, replacing any declared buttons. It will be added
                            to the AlertDialog's view hierarchy like any other View.
                        -->
                </AlertDialog>

                <ListView id="elementsOnList" defaultItemTemplate="elementTemplate" > <!--onItemClick= -->
                                        <Templates>
                                                <ItemTemplate name="elementTemplate">
                                                  <View>
                                                    <Label bindId="textoLista" id="textoLista" onClick="showDetailTask"/>
                                                    <ImageView bindId="icon" id="icon" onClick="checked"/> 
                                                  </View>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </Templates>
                                       <ListSection dataCollection="todo">

                                          <ListItem 
                                                icon:image="images/blank_check.png" 

                                                textoLista:text="{name}" 
                                                idTareas="{idTarea}" 
                                                nombre="{name}" 
                                                hora="{hour}" 
                                                fecCreacion="{dateCreated}"
                                                fechaTarea="{dueDate}" 
                                                descripcion="{description}" 
                                                estatus="{status}" 
                                            />  

                                       </ListSection>             
                </ListView>
    </Window>
        </Tab>
</Alloy>
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use an event?

Comment: Because I structured my app with two tab based, One tab where it show the form to add a taks and the other one to show the task status, so I do not know how can use an event because my idea is show to the user when the tab is pressed with different images in the ListView depending in the status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by binding the imageView to checked or blank image using `dataTransform` function.

here is what you should do:

in .xml File :

```
<Alloy>
  <Collection src="todo" />
            ...
            ...
    <ListView id="elementsOnList" defaultItemTemplate="elementTemplate" >
       <ListSection dataCollection="todo" dataTransform="myDataTransformFunction">
        <ListItem
           icon:image="{image}" 
           textoLista:text="{name}" 
           idTareas="{idTarea}" 
           nombre="{name}" 
           hora="{hour}" 
           fecCreacion="{dateCreated}"
           fechaTarea="{dueDate}" 
           descripcion="{description}" 
           estatus="{status}"/>  
       </ListSection>
```

and then in your controller .js you define the dataTransform Function like this:

```
function myDataTransformFunction(model){
  var transform = model.toJSON();
  //here I add a custom field to the model.
  transform.image = (transform.status == 1) ? "images/checked.png" : "images/blank_check.png";
  return transform;
}
```

for more details about data binding you can refer to the [Appcelerator & Alloy data binding docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding)

Comment: It's absolutely fantastic!, I appreciate your time the code works just fine, I will read carefully the link of documentation you gave me. Thank you again you made my day.